# Задача на JS - помогите реализовать

Tags: javascript

Помогите реализовать правильно.
Яндекс запускает сеть автономных дронов для доставки пиццы и хочет,
чтобы вы создали гибкую систему вознаграждений (ПиццаБаллы™),
которую можно настроить в будущем. Правила просты: если клиент сделал
не менее N заказов по цене не менее Y, он получает бесплатную пиццу!
Создайте функцию, которая принимает объект клиентов, минимальное
количество заказов и минимальную цену заказа. Верните список клиентов,
которые имеют право на бесплатную пиццу.
Например:

```
let clientsPizzas = {
  "Ivan": [22, 30, 11, 17, 15, 52, 27, 12],
  "Boris": [5, 17, 30, 33, 40, 22, 26, 10, 11, 45]
}

function(clientsPizzas, 5, 20) ➞ ["Boris"]
function(clientsPizzas, 3, 10) ➞ ["Ivan", "Boris"]
function(clientsPizzas, 5, 100) ➞ []
```

Примечания:
Отсортируйте возвращенный массив имен клиентов в алфавитном
порядке.

Comment: Начнем с ваших попыток. Где они?

Comment: А что вы уже сделали? Даже если не совсем правильно, покажите.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Всё в задании написано, что тут ещё помогать - не ясно

Comment: Мне бы логику выстроить, что то совсем не соображу с чего начать.

Comment: Опишите как вы сами решали бы эту задачу. Инструкция для человека: что где взять, что считать, с чем сравнивать, что в ответ выдавать.

Comment: *" с чего начать."* ---  Создайте функцию, которая принимает объект клиентов, минимальное количество заказов и минимальную цену заказа.

Answer (score 2):

> Верните список клиентов

Означает, что надо создать переменную типа массив, в которую будут помещаться клиенты, подходящие по условию

> принимает объект клиентов

значит надо пробегаться будет по списку клиентов и их значениям. Этим занимается цикл и [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
for (const [name, values] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  
}
```

Внутри внешнего цикла, описанного выше, будет ещё один, внутренний, который пробегается по массиву (по `values`). Узнать подходит человек под условие легко:

1. Объявляем счётчик **до** цикла (внутреннего) с начальным значением 0.
2. В цикле проверяем через `if` условие  `Y`
3. Если соблюдается условие, то прибавляем счётчик
4. За циклом проверяем, если счётчик равен или больше `N`, то человека добавляем в массив, объявленный в самом начале

Answer (score 1):

Однострочник :)

```js
const clientsPizzas = {
  "Ivan": [22, 30, 11, 17, 15, 52, 27, 12],
  "Boris": [5, 17, 30, 33, 40, 22, 26, 10, 11, 45]
};

const whoNeedFreePizza = (clients, minCount, minPrice) =>
  Object.keys(clients)
  .filter(name => clients[name].filter(amount => amount >= minPrice).length >= minCount)
  .sort()

console.log(whoNeedFreePizza(clientsPizzas, 5, 20)); // ["Boris"]
console.log(whoNeedFreePizza(clientsPizzas, 3, 10)); // ["Ivan", "Boris"] if sorted ["Boris", "Ivan"]
console.log(whoNeedFreePizza(clientsPizzas, 5, 100)); // []
```

Объяснений не будет, пока я не увижу вашу реализацию [алгоритма](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1488122/385375) Алексея Шиманского

Comment: Вроде sort не просили?

Comment: @Qwertiy В примечании требовали, вот я и добавил :)

Comment: Ой, я дотуда не дочитал)